# Windows Phone 8.1 - Is there a way to know if EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync has sent the email?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When I call

```
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
```

I don't find any reference that tells me whether the user has pressed the send button or the back button(back to the app).

How can I achieve this? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you can await for `ShowComposeNewEmailAsync` which is a `IAsyncAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. It's a launcher, so you just fire and forget. Whether the e-mail was sent or not is not returned to your app.

If you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmanager.showcomposenewemailasync.aspx) you'll notice that awaiting doesn't return anything, so there's really no way to know.